# Two entry boxes on one zenity command

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, zenity

Using zenity i can create an combo box like this

```
zenity --entry --title "Window title" --text "Insert your choice." a b c d e
```

How can i create two combo boxes in one dialog, i tried using the separator command like this

```
zenity --entry --title "Select Flash Drives" --text "Insert your choice." --separator="," --add-entry="IP address" --add-entry="PORT"
```

But it says

```
--separator is not supported for this dialog
```

Is it possible to create two combo boxes in one zenity dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, it's not possible. Zenity is designed "to create simple dialogs" and what you are asking for is that one tiny step further from *simple*.

I think you need to look for a different tool. [YAD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yad-dialog/) is a fork of Zenity that adds some improvements and might help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 4):

While two combo boxes are not possible, producing two entry boxes in one dialog is possible with the `--forms` option, which also allows incorporating lists (from each of which the user may select at most one item):

```
zenity --forms --title "Select Flash Drives" --text  "Select Flash Drives" \
--add-entry "Insert your choice" \
--add-entry="IP address"
```

or even

```
zenity --forms --title "Select Flash Drives" --text  "Select Flash Drives" \
--add-list "Insert your choice" --list-values 'a|b|c' \
--add-entry="IP address" --add-entry="PORT"
```

The main problem with `--forms` is that it does not allow for default values. (Unless the form starts with a list, in which case its first value seems to be selected by default.) The only work-around is to specify the default value in the question text (so that the user gets to see it) and then check if any value was supplied by the user in the script outside of zenity:

```
RETURNVALUE=`zenity --forms --title "Select Flash Drives" --text  "Select Flash Drives" \
--add-entry="IP address (leave empty to use 8.8.8.8)" \
--add-list "Insert your choice (leave empty to use C)" --list-values 'a|b|c'`

# extract the IP and DRIVE values
IP=$(awk -F'|' '{print $1}' <<<$RETURNVALUE);    
DRIVE=$(awk -F'|' '{print $2}' <<<$RETURNVALUE);

# [[ -z $var ]] is true iff the length of $var is zero
# the second element in && is evaluated only if the first one is true 
[[ -z $IP ]] && IP="8.8.8.8";                    
[[ -z $DRIVE ]] && DRIVE="C";
```